# GDB process not running

Tags: qt, gdb, qt-creator

when I start GDB, I get the following error message in debugger:

input:--- token barrier ---
debug:NO GDB PROCESS RUNNING, CMD IGNORED: -stack-list-arguments 2 0 0
debug:NO GDB PROCESS RUNNING, CMD IGNORED: -stack-list-locals 2
debug:SWITCHING OFF DUMPER DEBUGGING
debug:NO GDB PROCESS RUNNING, CMD IGNORED: set unwindonsignal on

Now if i set breakpoints there is only a few places where the debugger will actually stop , everywhere else the breakpoints are ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had added all the possible views for debugger (Debug->Views  then select them all)  this somehow made most of my code unreachable by breakpoints.  Is this a bug or a consequence of the type of views I added?